# Google Place Photo Requests API returns error

Tags: php, google-places-api, google-places

I am using Google `Place Photos` [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos#place_photo_requests) to get photos ...

So as per the site reference.. First requested for the `photoreference` using

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$store['lat'].",".$store['lng']."&radius=500&types=store&name=walmart&key=".$key."&sensor=false"
```

And I got the `photoreference` as

`CoQBdAAAAGIEWyhWUoIkJkoD6hkoAE0xrbj_JYyi1vm9SN4eP1NxNxAWTV21UJiLx4zB-Z5qBE7hAZIdaS7BWCPj9yNnYbJ3_NCHUBowyveWH8Tuagst-8qnfcBbIQa_WtE0yjub4SD8hrNXY-oxA139fmESJgNFPtZRw6H_2ot-wJxn8UhGEhBbMVy0BEk76MFRGIetwwDGGhRAJeKs1D5tjSP2PdFybPBjJiMmpA`

Then requested for the photo with the same key `$key`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBdAAAAGIEWyhWUoIkJkoD6hkoAE0xrbj_JYyi1vm9SN4eP1NxNxAWTV21UJiLx4zB-Z5qBE7hAZIdaS7BWCPj9yNnYbJ3_NCHUBowyveWH8Tuagst-8qnfcBbIQa_WtE0yjub4SD8hrNXY-oxA139fmESJgNFPtZRw6H_2ot-wJxn8UhGEhBbMVy0BEk76MFRGIetwwDGGhRAJeKs1D5tjSP2PdFybPBjJiMmpA&sensor=true&key=".$key."
```

But It returns error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

But the key is valid

Any Idea how to fix this ?

Comment: You've got ." at the end, are you accidentally appending something to your key?  What is the actual request URL?